# Does engine score correlate with winning chances?

Tags: engines, statistics, evaluation

I was wondering if there is a statistical or probabilistic (at least approximate) way of looking at a score of a chess position of a certain fixed engine, say "crafty version 5" for example.

i.e. maybe +2 could be interpreted as "if the engine keeps on playing, 60% wins white, 30% black and 10% draw. I know this isn't the purpose of the score, but maybe it can be translated to approximate probabilities, maybe someone has done a statistical test with hundreds of games to see the correlation. And the amount of draw maybe depends on the "sharpness" of the position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the website of [Houdini](http://www.cruxis.com/chess/houdini.htm), one of the best chess engines (see for instance [CCRL](http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/404/) or [CEGT](http://www.husvankempen.de/nunn/40_4_Ratinglist/40_4_BestVersion/rangliste.html)), the author writes

> Houdini 4 uses calibrated evaluations in which engine scores correlate directly with the win expectancy in the position. A +1.00 pawn advantage gives a 80% chance of winning the game against an equal opponent at blitz time control. At +2.00 the engine will win 95% of the time, and at +3.00 about 99% of the time. If the advantage is +0.50, expect to win nearly 50% of the time.

The [Chess Programming Wiki](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Pawn+Advantage%2C+Win+Percentage%2C+and+ELO) mentions a study where data from more than 400 000 computer games have been used to find a relation between pawn advantage (P) and winning percentage (W).

> W = 1 / (1+10^(-P/4))

Comment: Amazing that only one pawn gives so much advantage.

Comment: True, the 80% winning percentage for P=1 in case of Houdini is quite high. Especially when compared to other engines: according to the formula, for P=1, W=0.64. But, as you correctly mention in your question, the score has a different purpose and it is not necessarily related to the winning percentage.

Comment: P=4 and W = 91% seems rather low

Comment: Also check "Peter Österlund’s Texel Tuning" in Andrew Grant, Evaluation & Tuning in Chess Engines", which you can locate under [Andrew Grant](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Andrew_Grant) wiki entry were you will get his [work](https://pdfhost.io/v/Q~Yrnl8kj_Tuningpdf.pdf) on relating the engine evaluation to the winning percentage.